# Linking a MOSS calendar web part to a shared Exchange calendar

Tags: calendar, web-parts, moss

Can I link a MOSS calendar web part to a shared Outlook/Exchange Calendar so that changes are reflected in both?

Answer (score 0):

You can link the calendar itself, are you trying to link just the view being displayed in the webpart?